# pipe with material how to test

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular-test

I can't understand what is not correct with my pipe test.

It's a pipe for creating the MatTableDataSource from an array.

This is my pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';

@Pipe({
  name: 'dataSource'
})
export class DataSourcePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(array: any[]): any {
    return array ? new MatTableDataSource(array) : new MatTableDataSource([]);
  }
}
```

The test is for checking if the array is empty, it returns an empty matTableDataSource

```
import { TestBed, async, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { DataSourcePipe } from './datasource-pipe.pipe';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';

 describe('Pipe: Datasource', () => {
   let pipe: DataSourcePipe;

   beforeEach(() => {
     pipe = new DataSourcePipe();
   });


   describe('Tests', () => {

    it('providing an empty array returns empty matTableDatasource', () => {
       expect(pipe.transform([])).toEqual(new MatTableDataSource([]));
    });
   });
 });
```

this test fails:

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) Pipe: Datasource Tests providing an empty array returns empty matTableDatasource FAILED
Expected $._filter.observers[0]._parent._parent._parent._parent._parent._parent._parent._parent._parent.destination._next = Function to equal Function.
Expected $._filter.observers[0]._parent._parent._parent._parent._parent._parent._parent._parent.project = Function to equal Function.
Expected $._filter.observers[0]._parent._parent._parent._parent._parent._parent._parent.observables[0].destination.destination.array[0].operator.project = Function to equal Function.
Expected $._filter.observers[0]._parent._parent._parent._parent._parent._parent._parent.observables[0].operator.project = Function to equal Function.
Expected $._filter.observers[0]._parent._parent._parent._parent._parent.project = Function to equal Function.
Expected $._filter.observers[0]._parent._parent.project = Function to equal Function.
Expected $.sortingDataAccessor = Function to equal Function.
Expected $.sortData = Function to equal Function.
Expected $.filterPredicate = Function to equal Function.
```

and I can't understand why, I also console log both parts of the "toEqual" and are the same.

Can somebody tell me what are I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `toEqual` clearly isn't compatible with `MatTableDataSource`, which is a complex object with lots of internal functions that are unequal to another instance with the same data. You'll probably need to mock it out.

Comment: This kind of pipe is rather bad idea

Comment: @Antoniossss can you tell me why is a bad idea?

Comment: @jonrsharpe what should I mock?

Comment: The thing that isn't part of the pipe you're writing; `MatTableDataSource`.

Comment: mock the matTableDataSource may be enormous, can't I do anything smaller to test?

Comment: You will hit your application performance really hard. I strongly recommend evaluating the collection at the component controller level and binding DataTable to the final data source without a Pipe.